# CFNetwork Handshake Fail Error for programmatically email

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Ok for the life of me I cannot figure this problem out. I am utilizing a SMTPsender to send a email without going through the user mail UI. What I cannot understand is when I run my application in the simulator, it shoots out a email without any issues when the function "sendemail" gets called at runtime. Now when I run the test on the physical iPhone, it gets held up and stops the connection. Here is the log I am getting:

```
2014-06-09 05:59:11.601 MCDemo[916:60b] in send
2014-06-09 05:59:11.606 MCDemo[916:60b] C: Attempting to connect to server at: smtp.gmail.com:25
2014-06-09 05:59:11.920 MCDemo[916:60b] in applicationDidBecomeActive:
2014-06-09 05:59:13.723 MCDemo[916:60b] *** stopping watchdog ***
2014-06-09 05:59:13.725 MCDemo[916:60b] S: 220 mx.google.com ESMTP r132sm217421oib.11 - gsmtp
2014-06-09 05:59:13.726 MCDemo[916:60b] C: EHLO localhost

2014-06-09 05:59:13.728 MCDemo[916:60b] *** starting short watchdog ***
2014-06-09 05:59:13.801 MCDemo[916:60b] *** stopping watchdog ***
2014-06-09 05:59:13.806 MCDemo[916:60b] S: 250-mx.google.com at your service, [2602:252:d3a:ca70:cd5d:c927:578f:cc91]
2014-06-09 05:59:13.809 MCDemo[916:60b] *** stopping watchdog ***
2014-06-09 05:59:13.811 MCDemo[916:60b] S: 250-SIZE 35882577
2014-06-09 05:59:13.812 MCDemo[916:60b] *** stopping watchdog ***
2014-06-09 05:59:13.814 MCDemo[916:60b] S: 250-8BITMIME
2014-06-09 05:59:13.815 MCDemo[916:60b] *** stopping watchdog ***
2014-06-09 05:59:13.817 MCDemo[916:60b] S: 250-STARTTLS
2014-06-09 05:59:13.818 MCDemo[916:60b] C: STARTTLS

2014-06-09 05:59:13.820 MCDemo[916:60b] *** starting short watchdog ***
2014-06-09 05:59:13.822 MCDemo[916:60b] *** stopping watchdog ***
2014-06-09 05:59:13.824 MCDemo[916:60b] S: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
2014-06-09 05:59:13.825 MCDemo[916:60b] *** stopping watchdog ***
2014-06-09 05:59:13.827 MCDemo[916:60b] S: 250-PIPELINING
2014-06-09 05:59:13.828 MCDemo[916:60b] *** stopping watchdog ***
2014-06-09 05:59:13.829 MCDemo[916:60b] S: 250-CHUNKING
2014-06-09 05:59:13.831 MCDemo[916:60b] *** stopping watchdog ***
2014-06-09 05:59:13.832 MCDemo[916:60b] S: 250 SMTPUTF8
2014-06-09 05:59:13.920 MCDemo[916:60b] *** stopping watchdog ***
2014-06-09 05:59:13.922 MCDemo[916:60b] S: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
2014-06-09 05:59:13.931 MCDemo[916:60b] Beginning TLSv1...
2014-06-09 05:59:13.933 MCDemo[916:60b] C: EHLO localhost

2014-06-09 05:59:14.164 MCDemo[916:60b] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9807)
2014-06-09 05:59:14.264 MCDemo[916:60b] delegate - error(-9807): The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -9807.)
2014-06-09 05:59:19.611 MCDemo[916:60b] *** stopping watchdog ***
```

This is the code regarding the log:

```
-(void)sendEmail
{

    SKPSMTPMessage *testMsg = [[SKPSMTPMessage alloc] init];
    testMsg.fromEmail = @"test@test.com";
    testMsg.toEmail = @"*********";     //left blank for this example
    testMsg.relayHost = @"smtp.gmail.com";//smtp.mac.com";
    testMsg.requiresAuth = YES;
    testMsg.login = @"*******";  //left blank 
    testMsg.pass = @"*****";
    testMsg.subject = @"test message";
    testMsg.bccEmail = @"test@test.com";
    testMsg.wantsSecure = YES; // smtp.gmail.com doesn't work without TLS!

    // Only do this for self-signed certs!
    //testMsg.validateSSLChain = YES;
    testMsg.delegate = self;

    NSDictionary *plainPart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"text/plain",kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
                               @"This is a tést messåge.",kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,@"8bit",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];


    testMsg.parts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:plainPart,nil];

    [testMsg send];
}
```

Is there a reason why it will not work on my iPhone but works for the simulator?

Comment: -9807 means an invalid certificate chain, so there is some issue with your device not trusting all of the certificates in the chain.  Also make sure the time/date is correct on your device

Comment: Which was it?  The certificate chain or date/time?

Comment: My Time was off on my device.. All those debugging hours and turn out it was damn time :|

Answer (score 0):

The status -9807 means that the certificate chain couldn't be validated.  This can be caused by an incorrect time/date on the device.

Answer (score -2):

Import CFNetwork framework in your project

[image]